# Running CUDA unit tests on Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Is it possible to configure Azure Pipelines YAML file to run CI on computers that has NVIDIA GPUs?

I am able to create a custom image that has CUDA installed and upload it to dockerhub, but the computers that Azure pipelines run it's CI on seems to be CPU only machines.

Is there a way to configure the YAML file to pick NVIDIA GPU computers on Azure pipelines to run CUDA unit tests?

Answer (score 3):

The Microsoft hosted agents re running on [Standard_Ds2_v2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sizes-general#dsv2-series) Azure Virtual Machines that don't have GPU.

So if you want to run the CUDA tests you must configure [self hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops#install) in your machines that have GPU and run the Azure Pipelines in that agent.

To configure Self Hosted Agent you need to [download the agent and install him](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops#download-and-configure-the-agent), after it in the `.yaml` file you need to specify the agent pool. for example, you created a new pool `myPool` to your self hosted agents, so in the yaml:

```
# Instead of: vmImage: windows-latest
pool: myPool
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you show us a sample yaml file on how to configure a self hosted agent? I checked out the link but I am kinda lost since there isn't any sample yaml configuration file demonstrating how this work.

Comment: Is there a way to configure this so the self hosted gpu instance can turn on and off by demand? Microsoft hosted agents are up 24/7 but if I self host a gpu instance 24/7 the cost will be extremely expensive. Just to clarify, the self hosted agent you are referring to are something like Azure N-series machines and not a local computer, right?

Comment: @user3667089 The truth that I don't have experience with agents on Azure VM, our agents are on local computers..

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else coming across this, the way to get a self hosted pool that's not on all the time is to use a virtual machine scale set, which you can then scale to zero when not used. Azure DevOps will take care of the scaling for you very nicely.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/scale-set-agents?view=azure-devops#how-azure-pipelines-manages-the-scale-set